# Run jQuery split() function only if div contains certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, split

Here's the problem:

I'm splitting text before and after a forward slash (/). I then wrap each of the split parts in a different span class, so I can style them differently. However, if there's no forward slash in the text, it returns the word *undefined* onto the page. Since I don't want *undefined* to appear, I need to ONLY run the function if the text contains a forward slash.

Here's my current code:

```
$('.author-info').html(function(i, val) {
  val = val.split('/');
  return '<span class="company">' + val[0] + '</span>' + '/' +
  '<span class="job-title">' + val[1] + '</span>';
})
```

Which turns this:

```
<div class="author-info">
  Company XYZ / My Job Title 
</div>
```

Into this:

```
<div class="author-info">
  <span class="company">Company XYZ</span> / 
  <span class="job-title">My Job Title</span>
</div>
```

Once again, the problem is that **if there's NO forward slash, it returns the word "undefined"** onto the page. So the following code (notice the lack of a forward slash):

```
<div class="author-info">
  Company XYZ My Job Title 
</div>
```

Turns into this:

```
<div class="author-info">
  <span class="company">Company XYZ My Job Title</span> / 
  <span class="job-title">undefined</span>
</div>
```

In order to prevent the *undefined* text from appearing, I need this function to ONLY run if there's a forward slash in the **.author-info** div.

Is there some way to make that happen?

Thanks so much for any help you can give!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try ...

```
$('.author-info').html(function(i, val) {
  if (val.indexOf("/")>0) {
    val = val.split('/');
    return '<span class="company">' + val[0] + '</span>' + '/' +
      '<span class="job-title">' + val[1] + '</span>';
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this still returned the "undefined" text... Can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/rtkarpeles/1zs4Lyek/

Comment: Use `if (val.indexOf("/")>0) {`

Answer (score 1):

Use contains:

```
$('.author-info').html(function(i, val) {
  if(!$('.author-info:contains("/")'){
     return;
  }
  val = val.split('/');
  return '<span class="company">' + val[0] + '</span>' + '/' +
  '<span class="job-title">' + val[1] + '</span>';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an if condition to check if the entire text has `/` anywhere:

```
$('.author-info').html(function(i, val) {
  if(val.indexOf('/')>-1)
  {
     val = val.split('/');
     return '<span class="company">' + val[0] + '</span>' + '/' +
            '<span class="job-title">' + val[1] + '</span>';
  }
})
```